# Least mean squares (machine learning algorithm)

Tags: machine-learning

This is the rule:
\begin{align*}
\theta_j:=\theta_j+\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{(i)}-h_\theta(x^{(i)}))x_j^{(i)} \space (\forall j)
\end{align*}
I can't get the correct thetas, they quickly get to infinity or some very large numbers.
My question is, for $\theta_0$, $x_0$ is always 1 right? And so, for $\theta_0$ the $x_j$ is not applicable.

Thank you (Merry Christmas)

Comment: More information please.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Alex ; your question seems to be described as if you asked it to a teacher in the context of a course, i.e. where he understands all the notations you just used. We're not familiar with those, a little context would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question better suited to [signal processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Gigili thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like multivariate gradient descent.
In this case, indeed, for convenience we choose $x_0=1$, more explicitly $x_0^{(i)}=1 \space \forall i$.
By making this choice the hypothesis function of our $x_1...x_n$ features:
\begin{align*}
h_\theta(x)=\theta_0+\theta_1x_1+\theta_2x_2+...\theta_nx_n
\end{align*}
can be conveniently written as:
\begin{align*}
h_\theta(x)=\theta_0x_0+\theta_1x_1+\theta_2x_2+...\theta_nx_n=\theta^Tx
\end{align*}
When applying gradient descent to fit our $\theta$ parameters in the step that "descends downhill":
\begin{align*}
\theta_j:=\theta_j+\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{(i)}-h_\theta(x^{(i)}))x_j^{(i)} \space (\forall j)
\end{align*}
for $j=0$, given $x_0=1$, we'll be having:
\begin{align*}
\theta_0:=\theta_0+\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{(i)}-h_\theta(x^{(i)}))
\end{align*}
As such, one may say that " for $\theta_0$ the $x_j$ is not applicable".

The reason you "quickly get to infinity or some very large numbers" is that your $\alpha$ parameter is too large and in this case gradient descent does not converge. You must find the sufficiently small $\alpha$ parameter for which the gradient descent converges, and theory says that it exists. Notice, that if $\alpha$ is too small, the algorithm may be too slow, so you want to find an $\alpha$ just small enough so that the gradient descent converges, not smaller.